# Slidable Widget shows vertical lines while sliding - Flutter_slidable

Tags: flutter

I am using the [Slidable](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable) Widget which works pretty well, but there is a strange behaviour while sliding my container. Here is the code and a GIF to show the vertical lines that should not appear.

edit:
I use this slide functionality within my friendslist. Therefore i call the createSlidable() within a loop. Within the Slidable Widget there is another method to create the child container getFriendContainer().

[image]

```
  Widget getFriendContainer(Friend friend, int i) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 20, bottom: 10.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(13, 13, 56, 1.0),
        borderRadius: i==0 ? BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(25.0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(25.0),
        ) : null,
      ),
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 15,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
                height: 40.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  border: Border.all(color: Color.fromRGBO(119, 119, 136, 1.0), width: 0.5),
                ),
                child: Image.asset('assets/icon.png', width: 70.0, height: 70.0, color:  Color.fromRGBO(119, 119, 136, 1.0),),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 70,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "${friend.name}",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      fontSize: 14.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  )
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 15,
          child: friend.muted ? friendMutedIcon(friend) : Container(),
        ),
      ],
      ),
    );
}

Widget createSlidable(Friend friend, int i) {
    return Slidable(
      actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
      controller: _slidableController,
      actionExtentRatio: 0.15,
      child: ...,
      secondaryActions: <Widget>[
        SlideAction(
          color: getFriendContainer(Friend friend, int i),
          onTap: () {

          },
          child: Container(
            height: 50.0,
            width: 100.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: ...,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: const Radius.circular(25.0),
                bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(25.0),
              ),
            ),
            child: Icon(Icons.volume_off, color: ...,),
          ),
        ),
        SlideAction(
          color: ...,
          onTap: () {

          },
          child: Container(
            height: 50.0,
            width: 100.0,
            color: ...,
            child: Icon(Icons.delete, color: ...,),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
}
```

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Can you provide some compilable code?

Comment: what do you mean? I used this widget: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable. There you can find working examples. I cant see any difference with my code :/

Comment: But their example is working fine, right?

Comment: yes, it's working fine. But with my custom design the vertical lines showing while sliding

Comment: So I want to understand why it's happening, that's why I need the whole code.
It's not standard library, and bug could be on your or their side.

Comment: i edited my question

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this. Using the `IconSlideAction` Widgets instead of `SlideAction` the issue is solved.